# Como validar um XML pelo Schema XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

Estou tentando validar os valores de um `XML` através de um arquivo `XSD`. Estou tentando da seguinte maneira:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(xmlReader);
ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
xmlDoc.Schemas.Add(schemaSet);
xmlDoc.Validate(eventHandler);

static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e) 
{
    switch (e.Severity)
    {
        case XmlSeverityType.Error:
          Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
        break;
        case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
          Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);
        break;
   }
}
```

Mas ao debugar e executar a linha do `xmlDoc.Validate(eventHandler)` obtenho o seguinte erro:

> The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' element is not declared.

Já procurei em diversos lugares e não consigo solucionar o problema; Como posso resolver esse problema?

[XML](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0-_Y3gSzw2EaFdEcWtZY25iMVU)

Comment: opâ tinha colocado no titulo, alguem editou, estou utilizando o C#, quanto ao XML nao consegui postar pois é muito grande

Comment: Só uma duvida, qual o valor de `schemaSet`? Ou seja qual o Schema que você usa?